# Matplotlib button generating random circles

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

everyone! I'm using matplotlib and I have a field with randomly generated circles. Also I have button which has to generate new random circles in the field but every time I press it, circles are generated inside the BUTTON, but not in the field. Please show me what I'm doing wrong, I'm new to     python(actually started learning it yesterday). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

N = 10
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * 0.2
l = plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.8)


def gen(event):
    N = 10
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)
    colors = np.random.rand(N)
    area = np.pi * 0.2
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.8)
    plt.draw()


axgen = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bgen = Button(axgen, 'Generate')
bgen.on_clicked(gen)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell matplotlib that you want to use the main figure axis to draw the points. By calling `plt.scatter` you tell matplotlib to use the current axis, which in your case happens to be the button itself. Here's a modified version of your code that uses explicit axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

N = 10
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * 0.2
l = plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.8)


def gen(event):
    N = 10
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)
    colors = np.random.rand(N)
    area = np.pi * 0.2
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.8)
    fig.canvas.draw()


axgen = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bgen = Button(axgen, 'Generate')
bgen.on_clicked(gen)

plt.show()
```

Notice that I also store the current figure instance in `fig` to update the whole figure using `fig.canvas.draw()`. `plt.draw()`, which you used, would also work, but might run into similar problems, if you have multiple figures.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have more than one axes, it's crucial to keep track in which axes to plot. Instead of using the pyplot commands, you should rather stick to the matplotlib api, plotting explicitely to an axes. `ax.scatter()`instead of `plt.scatter`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

N = 10
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * 0.2
l = ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.8)


def gen(event):
    N = 10
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)
    colors = np.random.rand(N)
    area = np.pi * 0.2
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.8)
    plt.draw()


axgen = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bgen = Button(axgen, 'Generate')
bgen.on_clicked(gen)


plt.show()
```